# In order for tech to complete does the production building need to stay attached?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

Playing as Terran, do you need to keep your barracks attached to a tech lab in order for research to complete?

For example: You have a Barracks connected to a tech lab. You begin Stimpack Research. Can you fly away your barracks and still have the technology researching?

If you can't and you fly it away do you receive your money back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After testing it a few minutes ago I discovered the following things.
1. The tech lab must stay attached 
2. If the barracks lands down next to the tech lab immediately afterword, tech is not resumed and must be restarted.
3. The minerals/vespine gas spent will be refunded.

Comment: Are you serious... at least you will not get points for this :)

Answer (score 4):

The Tech Lab must stay attached.

The research stops if:

- your Tech Lab is destroyed
- your Barracks is destroyed
- you decide to lift off your Barracks and fly it to another location

Comment: The need to cancel the research is not true. It automatically stops research without you having to stop it first.

Comment: @chobok: I removed the explanation. Please explain if you disagree. Still, thanks for your edit.